# Blender mouse function is not working properly?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I used the new mouse actuator and had it used for mouselook. It seems that you would need to turn an amount until the mouselook actually works. My threshold is set to 0, and I am very confused of why this still happens. I would like to have my mouselook start to move as soon as I move my mouse. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I noticed the same problem. This only seems to be happening in the Y axis. X axis is smooth. What OS are you on? Could be a bug.

Comment: I am currently running blender (64-bit if that helps) on a windows 8.1 operating system.

Comment: I submitted a bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T43732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to the way that blender get Screen resolutions (returning integers). Due to this, a little threshold had to be setted internally.
Currently, a fix was summitted https://developer.blender.org/rBee58d449455df9470c4a0a902056b8c2001128bf rounding to upper pixel and removing that little intern threshold.

Could you download a dayly build https://builder.blender.org/download/ and check that the issue has been fixed for you?

**Note: For a better behaviour, to use a mouse sensor instead of a always sensor**

[image]

**Note2: it's known that with a setup with 2 monitors the mouse look doesn't work correctly. I'm investigating how to fix it.**

Comment: Nice to see yet another developer around here :) Can't wait to see what the BGE will look like now that it's being actively developed :D

Comment: Before I do anything, which piece of code would I use? The one on the right or left?

Comment: The code is already committed in the master. To use it you only have to download a dayly build

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem, and it can be fixed by simply lowering the sensitivity. Note that the reset distance is still smaller than the trigger distance, so this does not fix the problem completely, it only makes almost un-noticable and more bearable.

[image]
                     **With problem**                                                          **Improved**

The reason this happens is that the game engine, when calculating the mouse's movement, resets the mouse to the center of the screen slightly before it detects the new position.
If you do not move the mouse fast enough, the game engine resets the cursor to the center before it can detect it's movement.

Comment: Yes, that helps, but for people like me who have mice with 10000 dpi, we need every bit to work. The dpi is very high as I love to run softwares and have my mouse be able to move every bit, and be, for example, more accurate in an FPS. Also, it would be bothersome to have different sensitivities for x and y, I could make them the same but it would still be inaccurate as the problem still occurs on a much smaller scale, and you would need to move your mouse a lot to look around. Are there maybe any python scripts or something I can use to update the position immediately?

Comment: If you are okay with a Python approach: https://github.com/mikepan/BlenderGEResourceKit